# How do you use RedisSessionHandler in Symfony 4? Broken docs

Tags: php, symfony

The documentation is broken and leads to a 404 page. I'm not too good at reverse engineering classes like this, any tips on how to setup services.yml to use it?

Doc page 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html

Session Handler 404
https://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/RedisSessionHandler.html

Git Page for Session Handler
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/RedisSessionHandler.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define 2 services:

- One for the Redis connection.
- One for `RedisSessionHandler` that will make use of that connection.

Edit the services file:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    Redis:
        class: Redis
        calls:
            - method: connect
              arguments:
                  - '%env(REDIS_HOST)%'
                  - '%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%'
            # If you need key prefix
            # - method: setOption
            #   arguments:
            #       - !php/const Redis::OPT_PREFIX
            #       - 'my_prefix'

    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - '@Redis'
```

(note that I stored here the Redis host & port as environment variables, but you can define them elsewhere if needed).

You can now make use of the service as your session handler:

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:  
    session:
        handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler
```

I struggled a bit too, and wrote a more detailed articled: http://blog.michaelperrin.fr/2018/08/14/redis-session-handling-in-symfony/

Comment: Just wanted to come back and confirm this all works. I do have a strange issue that the %env(REDIS_HOST) and port aren't being called from environment. I did a php bin/console about and shows the variables are setup though, and I'm using the services.yaml file. Guessing symfony bug? If i replace %env(REDIS_HOST) or port with actual value, it works.

Comment: How do you get the environment variables defined? Is it using a .env file, or maybe Docker Compose, or some other ways?

Comment: Seems I found the issue. %env(REDIS_HOST) has to be %env(REDIS_HOST)% . I didn't know I needed another %. This normal?

Comment: Oops, I just made a mistake, thanks for pointing this out. I am going to edit the post.

Comment: How to configure keys prefix?

Comment: @AlexanderMatveev I upgraded my answer with an example for key prefixes.

Comment: Coming back to this after a while, one thing to note, in cache redis://hostname is the format. in this one, it cannot contain redis:// , it's just the hostname.

Answer (score 2):

For adding custom prefix, maybe the following is better:

```
    Redis:
        class: Redis
        calls:
            - method: connect
              arguments:
                  - '%env(REDIS_HOST)%'
                  - '%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%'

#            - method: setOption
#              arguments:
#                  # @see https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files
#                  - !php/const Redis::OPT_PREFIX

    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - '@Redis'
            # @see https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html
            -
                prefix: ivannotes_
```